# Create a List of Specified Length in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I need a function that takes an `Int` (say `n`) and creates a list of `n` elements.

The function must have the type: `Int -> [Var]` where Vars can only be ints.

Comment: Which *n* elements does the function populate the list with? What have you tried? For instance, if *n* is 3, is `[0,0,0]` a valid output? Is `[1,2,3]` a valid output?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have only one value, hoogle is your friend:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate

Comment: This link would better explain how hoogle helps: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D

Answer (score 2):

```
type Var = Int

listOfN :: Int -> [Var]

listOfN n = take n (repeat 0)
```

This matches your specification exactly.